# Using Font Awesomne icons in horizontal list

Tags: html, css, icons, font-awesome

I am building a web site and I want a horizontal list containing three Font Awesome icons - log-in, favourite, and cart to look like this, with the words replaced by icons:

[image: A text mock up of the desired icon bar layout]

However, using the code recommended by Font Awesome:

```
   <div class="siteicons" >
                    <ul class="fa-ul">
                          <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-sign-in fa-lg"></i></span></li>
                          <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-heart-in fa-lg"></i></span></li>
                          <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart fa-lg"></i></span></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

results in only the final icon dsiplaying:

[image: Issue with non-display of icons]

The CSS for the element in question is:

```
.siteicons {
    grid-area: icons;
    justify-self: stretch;
    align-self: center;
}

.siteicons ul {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3,22vw);
}

.siteicons li {
    /* No bullets */
    text-align: left;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

To my understanding, the icons should display in the way the text did, but that clearly isn't happening.

Does anyone have any suggestions, please?

All the best,

Dermot

Comment: What is the version of fontawesome you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hello** The problem is that the icon classes you are using do not exist in the version you are using. See an example with valid classes:

```css
.siteicons {
    grid-area: icons;
    justify-self: stretch;
    align-self: center;
}

.siteicons ul {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3,22vw);
}

.siteicons li {
    /* No bullets */
    text-align: left;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

 <div class="siteicons" >
                    <ul class="fa-ul">
                          <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt fa-lg"></i></span></li>
                          <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-heart fa-lg"></i></span></li>
                          <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart fa-lg"></i></span></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

Comment: Hi, you were right - even though i downloaded just today from the FA site I had the wrong link - as you suggested this one is correct <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

Comment: Yes, it all depends on the version to use